# push notification for RSS Feed?

Tags: android

I want to send push notification to my user,when will i update some information in my RSS Feed,Now i am using third party tool like urbanairship,but did not support RSS Feed,Have any third party tool for notification,please give some  idea about that.

Thanks,
John

Comment: lets try to use Urban Airship...it's best third party to use,i too try to implement it..i can able to send text message to device,but problem in sending Rss feed updates.Lets try it..

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need real-time notification from a push service? How many update will your RSS push? Have you already considered polling your feed?
You can do that in minute with the BuzzBox SDK: it also has an RSS parser integrated to do exactly what you need.

http://hub.buzzbox.com/android-sdk/

Use like this:

```
 RssReaderTask.setRssUrl(this, "http://yourserver.com/feed.rss");

 SchedulerManager.getInstance().saveTask(this, "0 9-20 * * 1,2,3,4,5", 
                             RssReaderTask.class);
 SchedulerManager.getInstance().restart(this, RssReaderTask.class);
```

It will check your RSS once an hour (according to the cron string "0 9-20 * * 1,2,3,4,5") and it will create a notification in the status bar if anything new is found.

The Demo App is a good example of it:
http://hub.buzzbox.com/android-sdk/demoapp

Answer (score 1):

You can use a number of different services the following are my recommendation.

You can use [Google C2DM (Could-to-device-messaging)](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) to alert your users when there's an update to your feed.

For that you need your own server (there's no way around that). In the server you should poll your RSS feed and notify users when something changes.

The only alternative to polling that I know of is [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com/subscriber). They alert your server using [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmpp) or [PubSubHubBub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/).

However, they do polling and notify you when a feed changes. The largest time between the poll is 15 minutes.

Comment: Note that PubSubHubBub is a deprecated name (which refuses to die for some reason); the current name for the standard is WebSub. Also there are other WebSub hubs other than Superfeedr. Also you can initiate a WebSub push at the time of update, rather than waiting for the hub to poll.